# Why is my simple selenium script slowing down over time and how can I make this more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, selenium

This script sends text from text file to a local website , website sends back 2 values that I copy into a second text file. The input file is large but not huge(50,000+ words , 256kb). I understand that sending input to a site and waiting for reply is a slow process , but what I don't understand is how it slows down over time. The script starts off at about 10 inputs per second and after 30 minutes it drops to about 2 per second. After several hours , it is below 1 per second. I tried splitting the list into 4 parts , and running 4 instances of this scripts at the same time and this made the process much quicker.

I googled this and tested several theories. One was to use chrome instead of firefox. This seemed to have minimal or no effect. Another theory was about complicated calculations getting bigger over time , but I don't think this applies to my script. I watched task manager and the process takes 15% cpu and barely any ram. I would barely call this overloaded.

Is there any problems or inefficiencies with my coding or method that would cause this? How would I improve performance of my script?

```
import requests
import selenium

# py -m hhtp.server in terminal from within index.html folder to start localhost

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# list opener

file1 = open("list.txt")
file2 = open("outputs.txt", "w")

# load webpage

# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\users\\desktop\\desktop\\test\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://localhost:8000")

# click button and check box

button = driver.find_element_by_id("button").click()
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox").click()

# run list through site

for line in file1:

    # enter text

    input_field = driver.find_element_by_id("input_field")
    input_field.clear()
    input_field.send_keys(line)
    input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # copy outputs

    output_text1 = driver.find_element_by_id("output_text1")
    output1 = output_text1.text

    output_text2 = driver.find_element_by_id("output_text2")
    output2 = output_text2.text

    file2.write(output1 + " " + output2 + "\n")

# close files

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Without knowing what your site actually looks like or what it does is pretty hard to determine what the problem may be.
What you could try / check:

- seeing that your server is locally ran, are you sure that only the selenium script is slowing down? It may be an issue with your site that's causing the slowness

- again, not knowing what your app actually does, or who is maintaining it, check if it can be modified, even only for testing purposes, to support file upload and process rather something like line by line

Comment: Good Idea. I will test and post result.

Comment: What is slowing down exactly? And Are you watching the browser process, or just the python process?

Answer (score 1):

Hey from the provided information I don't think the website is slowing down, however, I also notice that u didn't quit your driver once the task was finished.
Simply use

```
driver.quit()
```

at the end of your code. I suspect the since you don't quit your driver it keeps accumulating memory and eventually crashes.

I also see that you imported the requests module but haven't used it.
You can skip selenium all together and scrape the website using them
here is a tutorial that may help you out
[https://devopscube.com/python-web-scraping/](https://devopscube.com/python-web-scrapping/)

Comment: I will add driver.quit(). But if its at the end of my script , the driver won't close until the program is finished? Which would mean that it won't increase efficiency? But this is good practice , you are correct. I will also remove request and make sure it still runs. I will check out your link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because each time you are concatinating/adding the new text to the past text of the output.txt for writing to the output.txt, the text gets larger each time you get the data from the localhost, which in turn causes your memory to slowly get more and more used, and as you are running it for hours it slowly slowes down your app.
For fixing it maybe you can try creating an output folder rather than an output.txt and create an infite loop, each the it loops get the results from your site and write it to a new text file like "output1.txt" "output2.txt" etc using the loop variable to create unique names. and that should prevent you app from slowing down, only downside is each output will be in a different file

Comment: I can try this , I'll write it up , test it , and then , I can write a short script to concatinate all the files into one file if this improves performance. Thanks.

Comment: This approach will most likely slow it down even further since for every iteration you will create / open a new file, write to it and then close it afterwards.

Comment: @Cosmin
The point of the iteration is to make sure each output is written separately while also keeping the old output saved in a different text file to prevent the outputs always concatenating to write which with time can take a lot of memory and slow the app and the computer. Instead of all the output data the computer will only need to remember the current output and iteration level in the ram which is infinite times better than the way he built it.